# Overriding HashSet's Contains Method

Tags: java, collections, hashset

Could anybody tell me how I can override HashSet's contains() method to use a regex match instead of just equals()?

Or if not overriding, how I can add a method to use a regex pattern? Basically, I want to be able to run regex on a HashSet containing strings, and I need to match substrings using regex.

If my method is not appropriate, please suggest others.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extend a HashSet the following way:

```
public class RegExHashSet extends HashSet<String > {
    public boolean containsRegEx( String regex ) {
        for( String string : this ) {
            if( string.matches( regex ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
RegExHashSet set = new RegExHashSet();
set.add( "hello" );
set.add( "my" );
set.add( "name" );
set.add( "is" );
set.add( "tangens" );

if( set.containsRegEx( "tan.*" ) ) {
    System.out.println( "it works" );
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a complete code about how to extend HashSet, then initialize a HashSet from the extended class?

Comment: This is O(n) with the additional (useless) requirement of hashing on insertion. Assuming the actual .contains() is never used, an ArrayList would work better.

Comment: An ArrayList would allow multiple instances of the same Object. If you use a Set, you probably want to have only one instance of on Object in it.

Comment: Actually, I need the contains value. However, I need it to match with regex instead of just equals() method.

Also, I want only one instance of an object in it. In this case, I want only one instance of each String in it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Google Collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/), and in particular, the [`Sets.filter`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#filter(java.util.Set,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) method. Much easier than trying to subclass a collection.